# System time moving slower by high CPU usage

Tags: cpu-usage, time

My computer used to have no problems staying at high CPU usage, until a few days ago, which I noticed that this would make the system time move slower. There is around 15 to 30 minute lag for each actual hour passed.

Is there any reason high CPU usage would make system time move slower? I don't think synchronizing the clock with a server very frequently would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable cause for this is overheating.
Check your CPU temperature. Overheating occurs at high usage and overall response speed will get slower up to the point of system halt, reboot or shutdown.